# Styled Components + TypeScript + new fonts Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fonts, styled-components

I want to use some font I've downloaded from the Google fonts on my React/TypeScript application. Unfortunatelly, I can not load the font.

I went through some articles describing the issue and how to handle it but with no luck. Take a look at the below files and let me know if there is something I'm missing:

I want to use the font here: Header.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import headerBg from "../assets/pattern-bg.png";
import GlobalFonts from "../assets/fonts/fonts";

const Header: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <HeaderSection className="header">
      <GlobalFonts />
      <InputWrapper>
        <MainHeading>IP Address Tracker</MainHeading>
        <label htmlFor="ip-input">
          <input type="text" id="ip-input" />
        </label>
      </InputWrapper>
    </HeaderSection>
  );
};

export default Header;

const HeaderSection = styled.header`
  background-image: url(${headerBg});
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  display: block;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-size: cover;
`;

const MainHeading = styled.h1`
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Rubik-Bold";
  // font-family: Rubik-Bold;
`;

const InputWrapper = styled.div``;
```

fonts.js

```
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";

import RubikBold from "./Rubik-Bold.ttf";

export default createGlobalStyle`
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Rubik Bold';
        src: url('${RubikBold});
    }
`;
```

fonts.d.ts

```
declare module '*.woff';
declare module '*.ttf';
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": ["src", "public/assets/Header.tsx", "fonts"]
}
```

file structure

```
src:
-assets
--fonts
---fonts.js
---Rubik-Bold.ttf
-components
--Header.tsx
```

Comment: I guess you're using webpack as well. If so, can you also share your webpack configuration file as well?

Comment: It's the create-react app app so the webpack config is hidden

Comment: If so, you also have to configure webpack to resolve your font file `.ttf` as well. Otherwise it won't get included in your bundle.

Answer (score 0):

You're using "Rubik Bold" as the font-face name but you're using "Rubik-Bold" in the css `font-family` property, I guess that's the issue

Comment: Good catch ! Unfortunately, after I fix that to be Rubik-Bold it complains about not beeing able to decode the downloaded font. I saw the stack thread about that but it's not helping in my case

Comment: I think the problem is on `url('${RubikBold})`, it's missing an `'` (or either you might have to remove the first one, I don't know what's the correct way of using it)